# LINQ For Parent and Child Collection

Tags: linq, children, selected

Following are my two entities

```
Public Class A {
public int id {get;set}
public string name {get;set;}
public List<B> games {get;set}
}

Public Class B {
public int id {get;set}
public string name {get;set;}
public bool isActive {get;set;}
public int a_id {get;set;}
}
```

Object A has the following data

```
1, name1 
2, name2
3, name3
```

Object B has the following data

```
1, cricket, true, 1
2, soccer, false, 1
3, snooket, false, 1

4, cricket, false, 2
5, soccer, true, 2
6, tennis, false, 2
7, poker, false, 2

8, cricket, false, 3
9, soccer, false, 3
10, tennis, true, 3
11, poker, false, 3
```

I want to my result set to contain only those rows from Object B where

```
isActive==true;
```

I tried all kind of queries i.e. with All, Any but I am unable to achieve the goal.

Comment: Did you try `.Where(isActive)?`

Comment: yes - the problem is the child list i.e. Object B is either returning 0 (when used with All operator, and or all when use with Any operator). My goal is to have all rows from Object A and only those from Object B where the condition is fullfilled

Comment: Why do not you have a where clause inside your select statement of list A. ListA.Select(x => new A() { id = x.id, name = x.name, games = x.games.Where(i => i.isActive).ToList() })

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter your sub list, here you can use projection to bind your objects to a new set of objects filtered as you want.

Example :

```
var filteredList = listA.Select(o => new A 
                                     {
                                         id = o.id, 
                                         name = o.name, 
                                         games = o.games.Where(g => g.isActive)
                                     });
```